# PayPal not returning any variables after successful transaction process

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, sandbox

I am trying to retrieve values on the return page after a successful transaction from paypal.
I have already enabled Autoreturn and specified the url for it.
My codes were working previously, it showed all the values, but it suddenly stopped working and just returns a blank now.
Please do keep in mind that I am rather new to php.

Here are my codes:

```
<form action='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post' >

                    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments.  --> 
                    <input type='hidden' name='business' value='business3@eparking.com'>

                    <!-- Specify a Buy Now button.  --> 
                    <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'>

                    <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase.  --> 
                    <input type='hidden' name='item_number' value='". $offenceid ."'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='". $offencetype ."'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='amount' value='". $charge ."'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='SGD'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='rm' value='2'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='return_url' value='http://mp25.bit-mp.biz/paymentReturn.php'>


                    <!-- Specify the Pages for Successful payment & failed Payment-->

                    <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://mp25.bit-mp.biz/paymentReturn.php'/>

                    <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://mp25.bit-mp.biz/userFines.php'/>

                    <!--  Display the payment button.  -->
                    <input type='image' name='submit' src='images/paynow.png' alt='PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online'>

                    </form>
```

paymentReturn.php

```
// STEP 1: Read POST data

// reading posted data from directly from $_POST causes serialization 
// issues with array data in POST
// reading raw POST data from input stream instead. 
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}


// STEP 2: Post IPN data back to paypal to validate

$ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// In wamp like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path 
// of the certificate as shown below.
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);


// STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

} 
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same problem.

The solution is to enable "Payment Data Transfer" option from the paypal account settings.
(Screenshot attached)

[image]

Your Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you addresses wrong responseURL to PayPal configuration.

double check on this

```
      <input type='hidden' name='return' value='______'/>
```

Also your responseURL should under same domain which you register to PayPal.

Comment: I do actually have the value specified, i'm just using '_____' to represent it instead. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: the value is the same as what i specified for the return url under website payment preferences.

Comment: thats i understand your concern with value="_____" , but its only happen when you provide wrong responseURL. because its seems your transaction done successfully but can't redirect back. so problem with only responseURL. check again.

Comment: I am redirected back to the correct return page, like so after the 10 seconds wait, but the values that are supposed to be retrieved from paypal are still not retrieved on that return page.

Comment: Check Paypal docs for retrieve value, might parameter name you are using is different than docs. check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077587/how-to-get-value-back-from-paypal

Comment: I've just checked them against the variables here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/ modified them to check if that was the problem but the values are still not retrieved. still an empty page, sigh.